# Combine a Room DAO Flow with manual network requests into one flow

Tags: kotlin, repository, kotlin-flow

In my repository I currently have two methods:

```
// watched by my viewModel, but this Flow lacks the information about
// failed network requests from getLatestItemsFromNetwork()
fun getCachedItems() : Flow<Result<List<Item>>> {
    // Returns Result.cacheUpdate
    return Result.cacheUpdate(itemDao.items()) // itemDao is a Room DAO Flow
}

// triggered when user clicks refresh button / swipe to refresh.
// note that this is not a Flow.
suspend fun getLatestItemsFromNetwork(): Result<List<Item>> {
    val result = remoteSource.getItems() // getItems() returns Result.success or Result.error
    if(result is Result.success)
        updateDatabaseCache() 

    return remoteSource.getItems()
}
```

Looking at both methods, I have three possible outputs:

1. Result.cacheUpdate
2. Result.success
3. Result.error

I now want to create a method

```
fun getItemUpdates(): Flow<Result<List<Item>>>
```

in my repository that can output these three Results, e.g. notifies about cache updates but also about network results. I am stuck how to do that, as I would have to somehow combine a Flow (the one from `getCachedItems()`) with `getLatestItemsFromNetwork()` which isn't a flow. Any ideas?

Hint: Updating the cache (items table) in `getLatestItemsFromNetwork()` on success (which would then trigger an update to the Flow of `getCachedItems()`) isn't the solution I require. This would loose the information about failed network requests, which I need in the UI to display an error message!

**My use case:**
I use this repository in a screen that shows a list of items, e.g. with title and description of each item. User is able to edit the title in a modal dialog (so stays on the same screen)

1. ViewModel shall get cached data on startup (could manually do this via a non-flow method `getCachedItemsNonFlow()`)
2. Immediately after that data shall automatically be requested from network (ViewModel could trigger that, but should get the reply via the `getItemUpdates()` flow). I need the result as `Result.success` or `Result.error`, it's not enough if just the cache is updated and triggers a flow update, as this will loose the error message in case the network request fails and no cache update is done (I want to inform the user that there is a network issue)
3. At any time, user can refresh data manually, as often as he wants. I need the result via the `getItemUpdates()` flow.
4. It's possible the user updates the title. That currently would trigger an update to the `getCachedItems()` flow that I finally want in the `getItemUpdates()` flow.

Comment: I think you need to describe more specifically what's supposed to happen. The Flow will keep returning results, but `getLatestItemsFromNetwork()` returns only a single result when you call it. So do you want to call it one time at the same time you start getting updates from the database? Is one of these lists of items the more authoritative list of items, or do you need to merge the lists from the two sources? Do you want to fetch from the network repeatedly? If network fails but you have database, which wins for you to show in the UI?

Comment: Side note, there's no reason for your first function to be `suspend`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks, suspend keyword removed :-) About your questions: `getLatestItemsFromNetwork()` can be called multiple times (as often as the user clicks a refresh button/swipe to refresh). If network fails, the cached data shall be displayed in the UI AND an error message informing about network issues. My ViewModel shall initially display the cache, then request network data (without user interaction) and after that the user shall have the option to manually refresh data using a refresh button.

Comment: So really, you only want the first value of the database flow, then, right?

Comment: no, I want to be informed about all database updates. While I will update the database cache when I get new data from the network (will update the code in my post to include that in `getLatestItemsFromNetwork()`) there can also be "partial" database updates in the items table, e.g. an item title that get's updated when user edits item details in a dialog or so. That also leads to a flow emission from Room and in that case I also want to update the UI / get this via the flow as a `Result.cacheUpdate` type.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Updated my question with the requirements and some background, hope that makes it clear :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would turn your suspend function into a flow that restarts the network fetch each time the user clicks a button, so we a expose a function for that. We can use a MutableSharedFlow as a basis.

```
private val networkItemRequests = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>(replay = 1).apply {
       trySend(Unit) // if we want to initially fetch without user manually requesting
    }

// Called when the user wants to refresh
fun makeNetworkItemRefreshRequest() {
    networkItemRequests.trySend(Unit)
}

private val networkItemRequestResults: Flow<Result<List<Item>>> = networkItemRequests 
    .map { getLatestItemsFromNetwork() }
    // You could use shareIn here if you want to use this on its own, but if we're only
    // using exposing it as part of the combined flow publicly, there's no need.
```

---

So, now you have two flows which you can do one of the following with:

- [`merge`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/merge.html)
- [`combine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html)
- Use [`channelFlow`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html) to do the complicated merging of the lists so you have much simpler work to do to collect the flow outside the repository.
- Keep them separate and downstream collect in parallel coroutines.

I think any of these would be valid. What you described in your question is a merge. If you merge them, and if you use `shareIn` on the merged flow in your downstream code, you need to be careful about buffer/replay size so you don't drop important values. For example, if you only have a replay of 3, but you get 3 network refreshes in a row, it might be possible you'll drop a Result.CacheUpdate if the collector is a little bit slow or after a fragment is recreated on configuration change or restoration. And `stateIn` would be completely out of the question because it will definitely drop values--StateFlow only holds one value at a time since the idea of state is that there is only one valid, most current state at a time.

The possible advantage with `combine` is that your downstream collector will have easy access to the latest `Result.CacheUpdate` and `Result.Success` both at the same time so the two lists can be compared.

Or with `channelFlow` you can create a Flow that has its own internal variables that you can use while collecting the other two flows and use these to determine how to re-emit a merged list with some logic.

Comment: thank you for all these informations :-) MutableFlow is one of the keys for me, as other methods can emit into it :-)